# Массовый UPDATE

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Всем добрый день.

Интересует следующий вопрос: мне необходимо обновить некоторые поля в таблице базы данных. В таблице 30000 строк, в каждую нужно внести по одному изменению.

Как мне написать SQL-запрос для обновления всех строк сразу и чтобы для каждой строки можно было поставить свои значения?

**Обновление**

В общем, есть массив значений КЛЮЧ => ЗНАЧЕНИЕ, в таблице есть поле, например, ID. Сейчас все выглядит так: берется массив, в цикле перебирается, и внутри цикла делается UPDATE * WHERE ID = КЛЮЧ. Но эта конструкция не подходит, так как очень долго выполняется и ложит сервак.

Comment: Поставить свои значения? Т.е. откуда то эти значения берутся? Их тоже 30000 с гаком?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

1. Создать временную таблицу со столбцами КЛЮЧ и ЗНАЧЕНИЕ.
2. Заполните её вашими данными.
3. Проиндексируйте по ключу.
4. Обновите основную таблицу, соединив её с временной по ключу (одним запросом).

Answer (score 0):

Только перебором, UPDATE... WHERE...

Comment: Сейчас сделал Конструкцию обновления следующим образом: есть массив значений, сделал цикл. В цикле сделал UPDATE WHERE для каждого значения массива. Тем самым уложил сервер... Нужно что-то легкое, типа массового INSERT.

Comment: Попробуйте завернуть все это в транзакцию.
http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.autocommit.php

Comment: Не совсем понял. Как мне это поможет?

Comment: По своему опыту могу сказать, что если нужно сделать пачку insert  (несколько сотен), то заворачивание в транзакцию ускоряет в 50-100 раз.  Так как по факту на каждую запись делается транзакция автоматом, а она отбирает от 90% времени и больше.

Я бы попробовал - это всего пара строк кода.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за подсказку, буду пробовать.